# Not Able to Access Windows 10 Folders From Windows 7 Machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, wireless-networking, file-permissions, file-sharing

I am new to Windows 10 (build 1903) and am trying to network the new machine to my Windows 7 machine, and I'm soooooo close ...

From my W10 machine, I can see my W7 folders fine. I had to log in with my Windows 7 login credentials but I have full read-write access to all my folders and its files.

From my W7 machine, I am able to get as far as to see my W10 user folders, but when I click on my user folder to drill down to Documents, Pictures, etc., I see the error dialog "XXX".

[image]

I'm stuck there because I can't figure out how to give user permission to a network user on the W7 machine. I've confirmed the folders are being shared but under Security, the only credentialed users are users on the W10 machine. I click Advanced to try to add users but it doesn't appear to allow me to add any outside those on the machine itself. There's no option to provide access to "everyone".

How can I provide access to my W10 folders for my W7 users?

Answer (score 0):

The following method works reliably for me with Windows 10 and earlier operating systems machines.

1. In Advanced Network Sharing, make sure the Network Cards are set to Private (all machines) and that Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing are both enabled (all machines). Make sure Password are being used.
2. Make sure all computers are members of WORKGROUP.
3. If usernames on machines are different, make one main machine and enumerate usernames and passwords from the other machines on this main machine. Use of the same Microsoft Account can avoid this.
4. Share the folders you want to the users you enumerated on the main machine.
5. Make sure Home Group is OFF on any machine that supports it. Windows 10 later versions eliminated Home Group.
6. Do not try to share user folders as they are very secure. Use a neutral folder (e.g. c:\Folders_for_sharing)
7. If you wish to use computer names, add them to the local hosts files of the machines. Otherwise use IP addressing
8. Restart the computers and connect as above.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if this is an option for you:

> Create share folder > right click > properties > sharing > advanced sharing > >Share this folder > Permissions > check 'full control' > OK > security tab > >add "Everyone", check "full control" > OK > OK

It may also be the case that the Windows 7 machine does not have a newer version of SMB enabled which the Win10 machine is using to share the files.